# Custom Designed Radio Button Inputs Styled with CSS and Voice over accessibility

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button, accessibility, voiceover

for my website i use custom Radio button based on this model:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/customInput/

it's working well with different browser and it's accessible with Jaws.

but when i try this solution with Voice Over i can't check the radio button. 
Is there a jquery event to allow this solution ?

regards,
Boby

Comment: I can't access your example that you posted.

Comment: @JoshAllen It works if you revalidate the URL after first fail. Or if you google it and come from Google? Accessible but not usable :(

Comment: If you're not too committed to that solution, check out http://uniformjs.com/ I'm not an expert in Voice Over, so I'm not entirely sure if there's a jQuery event for it, but Uniform JS has some extensible options you could probably use.

Comment: Sorry for the link, i have tested it before posting, I will test the uniformjs example with voice over.

Comment: the uniformjs solution is working well with Voice Over. So it's a solution. But if someone knows why it's not work with the first solution. i will be a good news.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a onclick event :

```
<p onclick="test" id="css">This is clickable</p>
```

Upon clicking this, it will execute a javascript function named "test" and with the formatting you programmed the CSS to do with the id "css". You can format anything and by just adding the onclick tag, you can do anything you want with a function.

```
<img src="https://www.google.nl/images/nav_logo195.png" onclick="search" id="css">
```